# How can I calculate the probability of K zero-crossings occurs in Bernoulli process at given length L?

Tags: bernoulli-process

In the Bernoulli process B[k] = 1(prob. p), -1(prob. (1-p)),

the probability of B[n] !=B[n-1] will be (B[n] = 0 && B[n] = 1) + (B[n] = 1 && B[n-1] = 0) = 2p(1-p),

so the probability which zero-crossing occur between n and n-1 will be another bernoulli process with

occur(prob. 2p(1-p)), and does not occur(prob. 1 - 2p(1-p))

I know this is wrong, but I don't know why.

what is the problem?

Comment: What is your definition of "zero-crossing"?

Comment: Your "another Bernoulli process" is serially dependent.